# how to make parent div equal to the height of only one child and ignore the other child?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with two children, one of which I want to position outside the parent, and I want the parent to match the size of the other child. I can use height: auto to make it equal to the sum of the heights of the children, but what is the proper way to make the parent size to one of the children and ignore the other child's height?

```
<div style={width: auto; height: auto}>
  <child1 style={height: 24px; width 24px; position: absolute ...}/>
  <child2 style={height: 200px; width: 200px;}/>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `position: absolute` to remove the one child from its parent container it will also remove it from the DOM and the parent would then only be able to reference its height based on the child that still remains inside.

Comment: interesting. that is what I thought as well, but it appears to be including the child. Child one is 24px and the difference between parent and child 2 is exactly 24 px. Need to figure out what else is interacting maybe. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why an absolutely position is affecting the calculation of parent height. I thought it would be ignored.

Instead, I just added a margin-bottom: -24px to balance out the 2nd child for now. Will find the correct solution later or check back here. I also want to try making a quick fiddle to verify that in a fresh environment the absolutely positioned child is ignored. I wonder if another css property is interacting with it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand the exact intent of your question, but is this what you mean?

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
<div>
```

```
div.a {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid skyblue;
}
div.b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: violet;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
div.c {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: palegreen;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

Comment: no I'm trying to make div A be the size of div C using height: auto. But I wasn't able to get it to work with JDawwgy's suggestion above. Instead I'm going to use a bad hack

Comment: In your answer to yourself, you say that absolute position affects the calculation of parent height. I do not understand what that means. Because it cannot be so. And here you are saying that you want to make A to be the size of child C that is using absolute position. I think you are contradicting yourself.

From your question, I imagine you want to match the height of A to B. No, sir?